# What are the values of Transition property of TransitioningContentControl from Silverlight Toolkit?

Tags: silverlight

What are the possible values that can take the Transition property of TransitioningContentControl from the Silverlight Toolkit?

That property is string type. I not found any answer, even in the silverlight toolkit official site.

Answer (score 1):

Your options are:

- DefaultTransition
- Normal
- UpTransition
- DownTransition

How I found out:

What my VisualStudio ObjectBrowser-Window told me about the `TransitioningContentControl`:

> public string Transition { set; get; }
>       Member of System.Windows.Controls.TransitioningContentControl
>
> Summary: Gets or sets the name of the transition to use. These
>   correspond directly to the VisualStates inside the PresentationStates
>   group.

and

> public const string DefaultTransitionState
>       Member of System.Windows.Controls.TransitioningContentControl
>
> Summary: The name of the state that represents the default transition.

and what opening the default template in Blend told me about the PresentationStates group ... wait a moment... loading blend... keeps crashing... I hate Blend ...now I got it:

```
<Style x:Key="TransitioningContentControlDefaultStyle" TargetType="TransitioningContentControl">
        <Setter Property="IsTabStop" Value="True"/>
        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Left"/>
        <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Top"/>
        <Setter Property="Transition" Value="DefaultTransition"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="TransitioningContentControl">
                    <Border BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" CornerRadius="2">
                        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="PresentationStates">
                                <VisualState x:Name="DefaultTransition">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="00:00:00" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)" Storyboard.TargetName="CurrentContentPresentationSite">
                                            <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00" Value="0"/>
                                            <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00.300" Value="1"/>
                                        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="00:00:00" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)" Storyboard.TargetName="PreviousContentPresentationSite">
                                            <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00" Value="1"/>
                                            <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00.300" Value="0"/>
                                        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Normal">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="00:00:00" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Visibility)" Storyboard.TargetName="PreviousContentPresentationSite">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                    <Visibility>Collapsed</Visibility>
                                                </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="UpTransition">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="00:00:00" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)" Storyboard.TargetName="CurrentContentPresentationSite">
                                            <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00" Value="0"/>
                                            <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00.300" Value="1"/>
                                        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="00:00:00" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[3].(TranslateTransform.Y)" Storyboard.TargetName="CurrentContentPresentationSite">
                                            <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00" Value="30"/>
                                            <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00.300" Value="0"/>
                                        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="00:00:00" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)" Storyboard.TargetName="PreviousContentPresentationSite">
                                            <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00" Value="1"/>
                                            <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00.300" Value="0"/>
                                        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="00:00:00" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[3].(TranslateTransform.Y)" Storyboard.TargetName="PreviousContentPresentationSite">
                                            <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00" Value="0"/>
                                            <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00.300" Value="-30"/>
                                        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="DownTransition">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="00:00:00" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)" Storyboard.TargetName="CurrentContentPresentationSite">
                                            <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00" Value="0"/>
                                            <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00.300" Value="1"/>
                                        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="00:00:00" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[3].(TranslateTransform.Y)" Storyboard.TargetName="CurrentContentPresentationSite">
                                            <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00" Value="-40"/>
                                            <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00.300" Value="0"/>
                                        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="00:00:00" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)" Storyboard.TargetName="PreviousContentPresentationSite">
                                            <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00" Value="1"/>
                                            <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00.300" Value="0"/>
                                        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="00:00:00" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[3].(TranslateTransform.Y)" Storyboard.TargetName="PreviousContentPresentationSite">
                                            <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00" Value="0"/>
                                            <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00.300" Value="40"/>
                                        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <Grid>
                            <ContentPresenter x:Name="PreviousContentPresentationSite" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}" Content="{x:Null}" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}">
                                <ContentPresenter.RenderTransform>
                                    <TransformGroup>
                                        <ScaleTransform/>
                                        <SkewTransform/>
                                        <RotateTransform/>
                                        <TranslateTransform/>
                                    </TransformGroup>
                                </ContentPresenter.RenderTransform>
                            </ContentPresenter>
                            <ContentPresenter x:Name="CurrentContentPresentationSite" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}" Content="{x:Null}" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}">
                                <ContentPresenter.RenderTransform>
                                    <TransformGroup>
                                        <ScaleTransform/>
                                        <SkewTransform/>
                                        <RotateTransform/>
                                        <TranslateTransform/>
                                    </TransformGroup>
                                </ContentPresenter.RenderTransform>
                            </ContentPresenter>
                        </Grid>
                    </Border>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```